# Postgresql in Colab using the wrong link

Tags: postgresql, linux

So I am trying to set up Django and PostgreSQL in Google Colab but I ran into an error when trying to test postgres. I created the user, password and the database and it says that my db called "restdb" exists. However, I set up the connection as follows:

```
%env DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/restdb
```

I then loaded the sql extension and tried the following:

```
%%sql
select * from information_schema.columns;
```

But the output is:

```
* postgresql://postgres:***@localhost:5432/sampledb
(psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  database "sampledb" does not exist
```

I am not sure why it is using sampledb in the url. I want to test this before I move the credentials to the Django settings. Any idea how to test this with Django? I usually use DataGrip but now I am in this new environment. Or if you can provide me with the best option to work with colab and postgresql